# How to get Office 365 service location via API

Tags: api, cloud, office365

I am trying to find the region of an Office 365 service. [Microsoft's Office 365 documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/online/legal/v2/?docid=25) states that the data storage regions are disclosed to the customer.

Is it possible to find a service's region via an API request?

I've been looking through documentation on the [Service Communications API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776043.aspx#sectionSection6), the [reporting web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984325.aspx), and the [unified API](http://dev.office.com/unifiedAPIs), but have found no mention on how to get the service's region.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't an API to get the service region.

You can get this information using powershell:
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Get-Mailbox -Identity magrom@contoso.onmicrosoft.com | fl

You can look at the OrganizationId field to see which region your tenant is in.

Comment: When I look at the OrganizationId field, I don't see any regions in the returned value. Instead, I see something like:

BLAH.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations/test.onmicrosoft.com - BLAH.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/ConfigurationUnits/test.onmicrosoft.com/Configuration


I do see a "UsageLocation" field that returns the value "United States". It doesn't exactly match up with the regions listed in the doc above.

Comment: You can look at the first 3 letters of BLAH to determine the region. For example EURPR05A002 means that the account is hosted in EUR (Europe). Other possible values include NAM (North America), LAM (Latin America), APC (Asia Pacific), JPN (Japan), and AUS (Australia). However, this is not a very accurate representation. Office 365 is a global service and service location varies by workload and tenant.